# stop touch pad from scrolling Ubuntu 23.04 and Dell

Tags: dell, touchpad, scrolling, 23.04

Latitude E5470 and Ubuntu 23.04. the touchpad scrolls the screen when I'm moving the pointer to select objects. Almost impossible to use the computer as the screen jumps around and if I use the pointer the screen scrolls. Want to get back to just scroll bars working.  not interested in using two finger touch or any of those gestures.   Just want normal scroll by using scroll bars.  xinput says I have alps touchpad.  If I turn off touchpad in settings nothing changes. same behavior. It's taken half an hour to type this due to screen and pointer  jumping around.

glh a

Comment: Just to confirm, you've disabled the touchpad in the "Mouse & Touchpad" section of the settings, and the cursor is *still* moving when the touchpad is grazed? 

Comment: Yes, touchpad is disabled.  And in tweaks app, inactivate while typing is checked. This does not work.   When I attach a wired mouse the cursor jumps around still.  When I invoke the terminal command 'synclient TouchpadOff=1' the touchpad is off and the cursor doesn't jump nor does the random screen scrolling happen (because it is off).  Very inconvenient to have to use a mouse and turn off the touchpad via the terminal to actually type.